# SQL update multiple rows with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name   id  Col1  Col2  Col3 
Row1   1    6     1     A    
Row2   2    2     3     B    
Row3   3    9     5     B    
Row4   4    16    8     C
```

I want to update the column with condition.

In first row,

```
update col2 = Col1+0 if Col3 = A 
OR 
col2 = Col1-0 if Col3 = B 
OR 
col2 = Col1*0 if Col3 = C
```

In second row,

```
update col2 = (previous col2) + Col1 if Col3 = A 
OR
col2 = (previous col2) - Col1 if Col3 = B 
OR
col2 = (previous col2) * Col1 if Col3 = C
```

The same goes to third row

Comment: mysql..thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with a case statement and variables:

```
set @prev_col2 = 0;

update t
    set col2 = (case when (@col2 := @prev_col2) = NULL then -1 -- never happens
                     when (@prev_col2 := col2) = NULL then -1  -- never happens
                     when col3 = 'A' then Col1 + @col2
                     when col3 = 'B' then Col1 - @col2
                     when Col3 = 'C' then col1 * @col2
                end)
    order by id;
```

Comment: Why got duplicate? when (@col2 := @prev_col2) = NULL then -1 -- never happens
                 when (@prev_col2 := col2) = NULL then -1  -- never happens

Comment: @LimNeo . . . Because the variables need to be assigned the appropriate values.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (case when (@col2 := @prev_col2) = NULL then -1
                 when (@prev' at line 2

Comment: After you added 'set', the return results update all rows became 0.

Comment: Are you sure to use @col2:=@prev_col2?

Comment: @LimNeo . . . I'm pretty sure.  First assign the previous value to `@col2`.  Then assign the current value to the variable for the previous one.  Then march forward and do the arithmetic.